# VScode Extension API: How to access commandHistory api and serviceHistory?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Command history api,

Or the action: `CommandHistory.clear()` as per [commandsQuickAccess.ts#L208](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/c4769cfdcd522942f3d4c27cacaa13deb8905dac/src/vs/workbench/contrib/quickaccess/browser/commandsQuickAccess.ts#L208)

Also the action: `historyService.clear()` as per [editorActions.ts#L1783](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/c4769cfdcd522942f3d4c27cacaa13deb8905dac/src/vs/workbench/browser/parts/editor/editorActions.ts#L1783)

And also as it was asked before. Is there any way to access some of the internal APIs? Or the ServiceAccessor? (historyService, and any others)

### Note:

The question is about the exact internal function mentionned above. Not the actions bellow which the lines i shared were part of there implementation:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.clearCommandHistory');

vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.clearEditorHistory');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these work for you:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.clearCommandHistory');

vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.clearEditorHistory');
```

They should do the same thing as the internal functions you cited.

As to your other questions about directly accessing other internal functions - if they aren't explosed in the api at [vscode:api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri), then I think the answer is no.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to re-implemented those actions to make the confirm dialog optional through settings (adding contribution). I already know about that. And the dialog right now always runs. I'm also creating an issue for that and contributing a PR to add settings to make the confirm dialog go optional. However, before that, i wanted to write a short extension. However, I hit a block with the api.

Comment: Forget to thank you. Thank u a lot as well.

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156418 (if seen as should happen, vote up for it through a thumbnail up).
PR: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/156421